# Replacement character appears after minification

Tags: javascript, jenkins, msbuild, minify

We using Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll to join and minification js/css files.

MSBuild script:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/MsBuild/2003">
    <UsingTask TaskName="JavaScriptCompressorTask" AssemblyFile="..\..\..\Soft\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor v2.4.0.0\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll" />
    <Target Name="Minify">
      <ItemGroup>
        <HeaderJavaScriptFiles Include="../Static/js/script-1.js"/>
        <HeaderJavaScriptFiles Include="../Static/js/script-2.js"/>
      </ItemGroup>
      <JavaScriptCompressorTask
          SourceFiles="@(HeaderJavaScriptFiles)"
          DeleteSourceFiles="false"
          OutputFile="../Static/js/scripts.min.js"
          CompressionType="Standard"
          ObfuscateJavaScript="True"
          PreserveAllSemicolons="False"
          DisableOptimizations="No"
          EncodingType="Default"
          LineBreakPosition="-1"
          LoggingType="Info"
          ThreadCulture="en-en"
          IsEvalIgnored="false"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

We have a "...run('-')..." in one of the js files. This em dash replaced by the replacement character (�) if the script is run on CI (we using Jenkins).

What could be the reason that CI isn't able to render a stream of data to a correct symbol?

**UPD:** 'Em dash' was replaced by '?' when I changed the EncodingType to ASCII.
'Em dash' remains the same when I changed the EncodingType to UTF8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTF8 should be used in the EncodingType.